# how to delete particular record from parse table in android?

Tags: android, parse-platform

delete particular record from parse table.

```
deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ParseObject.createWithoutData("Country", objID)
                    .deleteEventually();
            Intent i = new Intent(SingleItemView.this, MainActivity.class);
            SingleItemView.this.finish();
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Comment: What are we talkin about? SQLite? please post some more code. And the logcat, in case you have errors.

Comment: not SQLite i required code for www.parse.com table.. parseObject

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(TABLE_NAME);
    query.whereEqualTo("groupname", groupName);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> invites, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                // iterate over all messages and delete them
                for(ParseObject invite : invites)
                {
                     invite.deleteInBackground();
                }
            } else {
                //Handle condition here
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about ParseObject. Try with `deleteInBackground()`. 
As per doc https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html

```
deleteEventually() : Deletes this object from the server at some unspecified time in the future, even if Parse is currently inaccessible.

deleteInBackground() : Deletes this object on the server in a background thread.
```